# VPN Connection Manager in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vpn

I want to create a VPN Connection Manager on user's PC. The connection Manager must set up 3 VPN protocols on user's PC for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8.

PPTP and
L2TP/IPSec and
OpenVPN

The Connection Manager shall receive server list from our servers.

Please help me to soulve the above issue.  I google it since last 2 days bit not find any approproate solution to this. So please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find details on creating a VPN Connection in .NET using:

[Set up VPN Connection using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/28125f40-9c3b-4e77-9bfb-8a975e9b3457/)

[Remote Access Server Spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446741)

However using ASP.NET is unlikely as browsers can't instantiate a VPN connection, they are sandboxed away from that functionality. Even services like GoToMyPC have a desktop client to perform the main functionality.

However you could create the RAS file then provide a download link on a website to it.

You can find the file at:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk

The person downloading the file can then just import that and have all the set up provided.